# iOS: Saving high-score locally

Tags: ios, save

I want to save an high-score for local use only. A single int, that holds your highest score so i can test against it when a new score is made.

Would you recommend using the plist?

Something like:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Info.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];

versionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,60,25)]; // for example
versionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
versionLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
versionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
NSString *versionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%@", [plistData objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]];
versionLabel.text = versionString;
[self.view addSubview:versionLabel];
```

will this data be available the next time the app is opened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest and easiest thing to do, IMHO, would be to use NSUserDefaults. You get the speed of reading/writing to a plist, but you don't need to deal with creating a whole new file just for a single value. The code for setting the high score would look like this..

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:100 forKey:@"high_score"];
```

Boom, that's all you need. Then, when you next launch the app and want to check that high score, perhaps in a -(void)gameEnded method, or - (void)viewDidLoad, you just say

```
NSInteger lastHighScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"high_score"];
```

lastHighScore will now be the value stored in the user defaults, which you previously saved. Using setInteger:forKey: will overwrite the previous value if the key already exists.

Comment: This works well, but a caveat for those of you who want to eventually make these scores global (ie with game center or ngmoco or whatever): `NSUserDefaults` is just a plist. It's extremely trivial for someone who's jailbroken their phone to go in and change these values to give themselves high scores.

Comment: That's good to know. I've never done anything with GameCenter or hacking plists with a jail broken phone. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Don't forget to synchronize (if you want it to get written on disk immediately. Or it might not be there when you need it)
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];